# Am I wrong to flag an OP answering their question multiple times?

Tags: discussion, flags, self-answer, specific-answer

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484723/automatically-preserving-id-argument-across-different-actions-on-the-same-cont), the OP has asked a question and then posted 2 solutions neither of which is satisfactory. Personally, I think those details should be part of the question (clarification of attempts to date and why they're not acceptable) but clearly the OP disagrees with me.

My reasons stem from:

- The "useless" answers could be pushed below useful ones so new visitors won't see all the information
- Seeing 2 answers on a Q may deter others from visiting and trying to answer
- It's untidy

I'd like to know what others think? Am I wrong on this?

Comment: newcomers often use answers to provide more details. If you can, comment on the question encouraging the OP to edit the question instead. After an hour or so (on SO - longer on other sites) edit the question yourself if you can. If you can only suggest edits, be sure to say in the edit summary that you are pasting in information from a comment, otherwise the edit may well be rejected. And then, if you can, flag the answers as "not an answer" so they can be cleaned up.

Comment: @KateGregory I did post on an answer suggesting the answers be added to the question. The OP disagreed with me (It seems it's since been tidied up and my comments deleted along with the answer). Since the OP disagreed, I felt I was out of options except to ask others to review and offer guidance (Which was part of my reason for posting this)

Comment: @KateGregory also, the OP in this case has been a member for over 3 years and has 1800+rep, so this is less of a newcomer not understanding, it is an established user not understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging by the comment upvotes, my comment might be strong enough to be an answer, so I am reposting it....

I'm not familiar enough with the technologies involved to assess the validity of the answers, but the 1st answer [now deleted 10K only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13484789/552792) seems to be more of a commentary:

> Another solution suggested by @MikeSW was to subclass Route class and then add custom "id" propagation logic in there:
>
> [ASP.NET MVC: The right way to propagate query parameter through all ActionLinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442494/asp-net-mvc-the-right-way-to-propagate-query-parameter-through-all-actionlinks)
>
> What I don't like about this is that it feels like a hack of the frameworks internals. I hope there is an officially supported way of doing this.

I think it should be an edit to the question, just based on how it is worded (or edited to remove the discussion aspect).

The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13484752/250725) at least looks like an answer, so it might be ok (if the content is good).

However, even give this, the structure of his responses just has a help forum feel where the OP continues to provide running updates on changes to the code in an effort to get more and different feedback (or maybe the feel of a whiteboard session where you are working out the problems with your team).  Even if the answers are valid responses and work, they just don't have the feel of a true Q&A.

Comment: I think the answers have moved around randomly, since they're both 0 scored. Can you post links identifying which one is the "first" answer and which one is your "second" as to reduce the ambiguity? Thanks. ;)

Comment: @jmort253 Sorry, done now for the undeleted answer (which was the chronological second answer), I had tag the first as "chronologically first", and figure it was assumed the 2nd was as well, but it would make sense to link to the respective answers.  I will need some kind 10K user to link to the other answer.

Comment: I went ahead and added in the link to the deleted post, as well as the content from the deleted post for context.